# Can preg_replace insert a space into a string?

Tags: php

Simple question (since my regex knowledge isn't very strong!): If I've got a string of, say, 10 characters, can `preg_replace()` be used to insert a string after character #3, if there isn't already a space there, or do I need to split the string 1st into 2 components using `str_split()`?

Comment: Can you give examples of the string(s)?

Comment: Well, to make it simple, they'll be UK style phone-numbers, such as 01234567890.  I want a insert a space, because I'm outputting data as CSV, and when the CSV is opened in Excel, the leading zero is removed (confusing my users!); if a space is included, Excel sees it as a string, therefore showing the leading zero.  If there's a more elegant solution than mine, I'd be interested to know it!

Comment: @ChrisW http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm#CSVAndExcel. It's usually best to ask about your actual problem instead of a hypothetical solution, otherwise you fall into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/169187) trap.

Comment: @Juhana - sorry, yes, I should have been more explicit to begin with. I'd tried the only Excel trick I knew of which was to add a `'` in front of the number, but this hadn't worked.  If you add this as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you could, but it's probably not the right tool for the job.

```
if( $string[3] !== ' ' ) {
    $string = substr_replace( $string, ' ', 3, 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With preg_replace,

```
preg_replace("/^(...)([^\s])/", "\1$str\2", $subject);
```

or using stirng function. **This is better**.

```
if($subject{3} != ' '){
   $subject = substr($subject, 0, 3). $str. substr($subject, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to call preg_replace, you can do like this:

```
$ins = " ";
$str = $str[3] != ' ' ? substr($str, 0, 3) . $ins . substr($str, 3) : $str;
```